# how to fetch wpf combobox selected value (key)

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to find selected value of wpf combobox here is my code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
dt.Rows.Add("ks34dsd45g6g74g", "Amisha");
dt.Rows.Add("2ks34dsd45g6g74g", "Rhitik");
dt.Rows.Add("ks34dsd45g6g74g3", "Aishwarya");
dt.Rows.Add("4ks34ds545g6g74g", "Sonam");
dt.Rows.Add("ks55dsd45g6g74g5", "Aamana");

ddl_BusinessIDNames.DataContext = dt;
ddl_BusinessIDNames.DisplayMemberPath = dt.Columns[1].ToString();
ddl_BusinessIDNames.SelectedValuePath = dt.Columns[0].ToString();
```

that means at run time combo box show the readable text to user ie Amisha,Rhitik,Aishwarya etc but my question is if user select "sonam" how to fetch the key of "sonam" ie "4ks34ds545g6g74g" because `Convert.ToString(ddl_BusinessIDNames.SelectedValue)` this code fetch the display text of combo box but what if i want to fetch the key of value "sonam"

Please suggest...

Comment: You certainly should not be mixing up your data access, your business logic and your UI logic within the same class!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`SelectedValue` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvalue.aspx)?

Comment: thanks for reply but By using SelectedValue property it return/fetch the displayed text ie value (ie Sonam) not key (ie 4ks34ds545g6g74g) and i want to retrive/fetch key of displayed text "Sonam" ie "4ks34ds545g6g74g"

Comment: @Raj: That should not be case if you set it up correctly, the `SelectedValue` should contain the value according to the `SelectedValuePath` which you seem to have set to the key column (in a rather questionable way, calling `ToString` on a column seems like a bad idea, why not just use `"id"`).

Answer (score 0):

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    label1.Content = dt.Rows[Combobox1.SelectedIndex][0];
}
```

`Combobox1.SelectedIndex` - represents selected row index of your datatable

`0` - column index in datatable with id, U want to get.

Comment: good logic but actualy my data not comes from datatable it will come from sql database using datareader or set so this trick might be not suitable. Is there any easy way to do this?